# Should I use .NET Standard or .NET 5/6/7 class library for creating nuget package?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-standard

I want to create a nuget package and I want this package to have backward compatibility. Should I use .NET Standard class library or .NET  5/6/7 class library?

Comment: Or you could directly target both (say) net462 and net6.0...

Comment: @marc_s that is simply wrong, and using netstandard is usually the *worst* way to offer .net framework support (due to the fact that the .net framework's implementation of netstandard2.0 is pretty... glitchy in places)

Comment: i would personally recommend choosing .NET Standard. Yes you will have to switch to an older language version (7.3) but it is not as hard as it sounds because most popular NuGet packages support .NET Standard. In short i would try to create your NuGet in .NET Standard and if you run into any problems you can change the TargetFramework in your `.csproj` to .NET 5, 6 or 7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is hugely contextual. Supporting older platforms isn't necessarily free, and claiming netstandard support is especially complex as it is hard to say that you've actually tested on all possible platforms that *implement* those netstandard tiers. Have you tested on Unity, for example? netstandard also has the most restrictive API of all possible targets.

Multi-targeting *can* be an effective approach, but you don't usually need multiple levels in netfx or multiple levels in "modern" .net (.net core, .net 5 and above) *unless* you're using different APIs in different environments, perhaps via `#if`. A common multi-targeted scenario might be "net472;net6.0" or similar.

In reality, I'd probably suggest "start with just net6 or net7", and see whether you *need* the other platforms. Adding at least one netfx tier can help legacy consumers, but... that is a diminishing consumer base.

Answer (score 1):

Create a class library with multiple TargetFrameworks:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFrameworks>netcoreapp3.1;netstandard2.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
</PropertyGroup>
```